# What is the definition of a function?

Tags: functions

I have heard countless times that a mathematical function must only have one output per input, and I have evidence against this, so I would like to know from everyone what is a mathematical function?

Comment: Show evidence that the original definition of a function is not correct.

Comment: The counterexample that you have is simply not a function (by definition).

Comment: It's just a definition, which means the only extent to which it can be "correct" or "incorrect" is in the extent to which people agree on the definition. This particular definition is not at all controversial, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: As you have the "evidence against this", what is YOUR definition of a function? What is "YOUR evidence against this"? It will enable to understand where you stand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a **function** mapping from $A$ to $B$ is a *binary relation* (let's call it $R$) on the sets $A$ and $B$ (i.e., it is a subset of $A\times B$) which satisfies the condition that for every $a\in A$, there exists **one and only one** such $b\in B$ that $aRb$.

I can explain more if you explain what "evidence" you have against the "one output per input" rule.

Answer (score 0):

The set-theorists' def'n: (1) The ordered pair $(a,b$) is $\{a,\{a,b\}\}.$....  (2) $A\times B$ is $\{(a,b) :a\in A\land  b\in B\}.$.....   (3) A function from $A$ to $B$ is a subset of $A\times B$ such that  $$\forall a\in A \exists ! b ( (a,b)\in f)\}.$$  The symbol "$\exists !$" means "there exists one and only one". In other words $$\forall a\in A \exists b\in B  \forall c\in B ((a,c)\in f \iff c=b).$$